# Conditional validation of an array in yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, yup

I'm struggling to implement conditional validation of an array using yup.

I have the following form:

```
enum Status {
 RED = 'Red',
 GREEN = 'Green',
 YELLOW = 'Yellow',
}

interface MyField {
  fieldType: MyFieldType;
  fieldValue: string;
}

enum MyFieldType {
  FIELD_TYPE_1 = '1',
  FIELD_TYPE_2 = '2',
  FIELD_TYPE_3 = '3',
}

const validationSchema = yup.object({
    status: yup.mixed<Status>().required(),
    fields: yup.array().of(yup.mixed<MyField>()).required()
)};
```

My `fields` field should be an array dependent on the `status` field, and contain values of specific `fieldType`.

Expample (pseude-code)

```
if (status === Status.RED) {
  fields: [{fieldType: MyFieldType.FIELD_TYPE_1, fieldValue: 'some_string'}]
} else if (status === Status.GREEN) {
  fields: [
    {fieldType: MyFieldType.FIELD_TYPE_2, fieldValue: 'some_string'}, 
    {fieldType: MyFieldType.FIELD_TYPE_3, fieldValue: 'some_string'}
  ]
} else {
  // some other combination
}
```

I know about `when` but not sure how to use it correctly for my problem.

This is a skeleton of my solution:

```
fields: yup.array().of(yup.mixed<MyField>()).when('status', {
  is: (status: Status) => status === Status.GREEN,
  then: yup.array().of(// no idea how to check if specific MyFieldType is contained inside here and that the corresponding fieldValue is not an empty string )
}
```